# How to delete files on a completely full NAS disk

Tags: linux, nas

A partition of [my NAS](http://www.ovh.co.uk/nas/standard_NAS_storage.xml) is full:

```
XX.XX.XX.XX:/nas-XXXX/backup   701G  701G     0 100% /home/nasBackup
```

I can't delete a file. I get an error:

> disk quota exceeded

I tried [this](http://www.bfg.uni-freiburg.de/doc/bwgrid/bwgrid-faq/deleting-files-when-quota-exceeded):

```
cp /dev/null one_of_my_file.tar.gz
```

But it doesn't work. How can I regain control of my disk?

Comment: Which NAS do you have?

Comment: this one : http://www.ovh.co.uk/nas/standard_NAS_storage.xml  This is NFS Protocol

Comment: Does this NAS have a management interface?  Perhaps you can delete some files through that?  It might run as a privileged user on the NAS which has less limitations.

Comment: The only thing that I can configure are partitions...

Comment: @akira: using /dev/zero is not going to help here. in fact, this would cause a file to be created that would take up as much disk space as possible. the only reason that /dev/zero works when erasing a disk is that the disk has a physical end and returns an error, stoping the copy. /dev/null is the correct source here because it results in a 0 length file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
> file
```

This command will clear all data in `file`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: do you connect nas server, may be you can delete in server.

Comment: I'm connected on my linux server.

Answer (score 0):

If your NAS has CD/DVD access run live boot of any Linux.
Mount the drive and work with it that way.
If this isn't possible, remove the drive and attach it to one of your Linux boxes.